# Multivariable optimization question - Rectangular box

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Find the dimensions of the rectangular box with largest volume if the total surface area is given as $64$cm$^2$

My approach:

$$
v=f(x,y,z)= xyz\\
2xy+2yz+2xz = 64\\
xy+yz+xz = 32
$$

Then I solved for $xy$:
$$
xy = 32 - yz - xz
$$
Substituted back in $v$:
$$
f(x,y,z) = z(32 - yz - xz) = 32z - yz^2-xz^2
$$
Then, I tried to find critical points for that function, to find where I could get the maximum volume:
$$
f_x = -z^2\\
f_y = -z^2\\
f_z = 32-2zy-2zx\\
$$

And now I'm lost, because if z=0 from $f_x$ and $f_y$, I can't get $f_z=0$...

What have I done wrong? Do I need to solve for just one variable and then substitute? What's going on here? I really don't get why it's "incorrect" to solve for two variables since my "main" function (in this case $v$) has these two variables in it...

**EDIT:**
$$
xy = 32z - yz - xz
$$

is not solved in terms of $xy$, since my right side of equation still has x and y... that's what I have done wrong?!

Answer (score 1):

Try $xy+xz=32-yz \Rightarrow x=\frac {32-yz}{y+z}$ to get the volume as a function in terms of $y$ and $z$

Comment: I've done that way and it worked... I just wanna get why my substition did not work. But I think I've figured it out... Check my **EDIT** to see if what i've said is indeed correct!

Answer (score 0):

By the symmetry of your problem the solution must be $x=y=z$

Comment: This is a nice way to approach the problem - but your answer is incomplete in two ways. First, you don't explain why the solution must be symmetric. Second, the OP wants to know what s/he did wrong.